# Accessing a QPainter in base class

Tags: qt, qpainter

I am creating widget classes that draw grids using QWidgets paint event. My base class BaseRenderArea contains this method:

```
//draws a list of guesses in the grid
void BaseRenderArea::drawGuesses(const QList <GuessPoint> &list, QPainter *painter)
{
    //QPainter painter1(this);

    QPen currentPen = painter->pen();

    painter->setPen(QString("red"));

    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
    {
        GuessPoint gp = list.at(i);

        switch(gp.m_type)
        {
        case GuessPoint::Miss:
            drawMiss(gp.m_row, gp.m_col, painter);
            break;
        case GuessPoint::Dead:
            drawDead(gp.m_row, gp.m_col, painter);
            break;
        case GuessPoint::Hit:
            drawHit(gp.m_row, gp.m_col, painter);
            break;
        default:
            ;
        }
    }

    painter->setPen(currentPen);

}
```

I am calling this method from the paintEvent of the derived class widget.

```
//the paint event
//uses the base class to draw the texts and
//the grid
//and then draws the guesses made until now
//as well as the score for each choice of the computer
void DebugRenderArea::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);

    BaseRenderArea::paintEvent(event);

    //to do: draw guesses
    drawGuesses(&painter);

    //draw scores
    //drawScores(&painter);

}
```

The drawGuesses method in the derived class is implemented as follows:

```
//draws the guesses made until this moment
void DebugRenderArea::drawGuesses(QPainter *painter)
{
    QList <GuessPoint> list = m_logic->getListGuesses();
    BaseRenderArea::drawGuesses(list,painter);

}
```

This approach gives me a segmentation fault in the BaseRenderArea::drawGuesses in the second line painter->setPen....

If I change the BaseRenderArea::drawGuesses with the following code (not reusing the QPainter created in the derived class but creating a new QPainter):

```
//draws a list of guesses in the grid
void BaseRenderArea::drawGuesses(const QList <GuessPoint> &list, QPainter *painter)
{
    QPainter painter1(this);

    QPen currentPen = painter1.pen();

    painter1.setPen(QString("red"));

    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
    {
        GuessPoint gp = list.at(i);

        switch(gp.m_type)
        {
        case GuessPoint::Miss:
            drawMiss(gp.m_row, gp.m_col, &painter1);
            break;
        case GuessPoint::Dead:
            drawDead(gp.m_row, gp.m_col, &painter1);
            break;
        case GuessPoint::Hit:
            drawHit(gp.m_row, gp.m_col, &painter1);
            break;
        default:
            ;
        }
    }

    painter1.setPen(currentPen);

}
```

everything works fine. My questions why ? What can I do to use the QPainter created in the paintEvent of the derived class in method of the base class?

Comment: setpen() is supposed to get a QColor as parameter, shouldn't you write Qt::red instead of QString("red") ?

In the first case you initialized the QPainter by giving it a reference to an instance of DebugRenderArea, and in the second case a reference to an instance of BaseRenderArea, is that what you wanted ?

Comment: The code works with QString("red") as well. In this case I think there are one and the same object except that one time the QPainter is created in the base class and the other time in the derived class. I am not sure how this should be done. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#begin) says that you can't have 2 active `QPainter`s on the same paint device.

So, because `BaseRenderArea::paintEvent` is probably creating its own `QPainter`, it might have invalidated the one you created before in `DebugRenderArea::paintEvent`.

You could simply reorder the two lines:

```
BaseRenderArea::paintEvent(event);

QPainter painter(this);
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked indeed. So Qt understands that the QPainter created in the BaseRenderArea::paintEvent and the one created in the DebugRenderArea::paintEvent refer to the same widget-